# java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse and iso8601?

Tags: java, java-8, iso8601

Why does the JDK8 DateTime library seem to not parse valid iso8601 date time strings? It chokes on time zone offsets expressed like "+01" instead of "+01:00"

This works:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01:00")
```

This throws a parse exception:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01")
```

From the iso8601 wikipedia page:

> The offset from UTC is appended to the time in the same way that 'Z'
>   was above, in the form ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh]. So if the time
>   being described is one hour ahead of UTC (such as the time in Berlin
>   during the winter), the zone designator would be "+01:00", "+0100", or
>   simply "+01".

**EDIT**: This looks like an actual legitimate bug in the JDK.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032051

Wow, after testing that new date time stuff for years, I thought they would have caught something so obvious. I also thought the JDK author types were rigorous enough to use a better automated test suite.

**UPDATE**: This is completely fixed in the current jdk-9 build. I just confirmed. The exact same parse command showed above fails in the current jdk-8 build and works perfectly in jdk-9.

**ADDENDUM**: FWIW, RFC 3339 based on ISO-8601, does not allow for this short hand. You must specify minutes in the time zone offsets.

Comment: And the question here is... ? (that is, may want to reword the title -- I assume you would like to know either why, or perhaps how to make that work)

Comment: Time zones are way more complicated than just an offset. You may be safe in this situation, but in general thinking of time zones in terms of offsets is a practice that should be avoided.

Comment: @StaxMan, clarified with the exact question... I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely fixed in the current jdk-9 build. I just confirmed. The exact same parse command showed above fails in the current jdk-8 build and works perfectly in jdk-9.

Using the new jdk-9 shell:

```
➜  jdk-9 bin/jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01")
$1 ==> 2015-08-18T00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Why is this marked as the accepted answer? The question asks why this is broken in JDK8. "It works in JDK9" isn't the answer.

Comment: It's a bug in JDK8, it's not fixed until JDK9... They should backport the fix to 8, but for the purposes of this Q/A, that's the definitive state of the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You [use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) this default formatter: [ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) (because parse `2015-08-18T00:00+01:00`).

In documentation:

> This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 extended offset date-time format. [...]
>
> The offset ID. If the offset has seconds then they will be handled even though this is not part of the ISO-8601 standard. Parsing is case insensitive.

[It's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#getId--) (you use only this for this default formatter):

> The ID is minor variation to the standard ISO-8601 formatted string
>   for the offset. There are three formats:
>
> - Z - for UTC (ISO-8601)
> - +hh:mm or -hh:mm - if the seconds are zero (ISO-8601)
> - +hh:mm:ss or -hh:mm:ss - if the seconds are non-zero (not ISO-8601)
>     (don't `+hh` like ISO-8601).

It seems like java.time (JDK 8) don't full implements ISO-8601 in all.

---

This:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01:00"); // works
```

corresponds to (roughly from source JDK):

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendOffsetId()
        .toFormatter();

java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01:00", formatter); // it's same
```

You can create own [DataTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-).

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = builder2.parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("X") // eg.:
        .toFormatter();

java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01", formatter2); // here you set +01
```

Instead of appendOffsetId() use [appendPattern(String pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) and set 'X' or 'x'.

Now, you can use your datatime `2015-08-18T00:00+01`.

---

Or... Use default ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME and add postfix `:00`.

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-18T00:00+01" + ":00");
```

But this last is bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code which is used is added by [DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneId--) which allows the formats for time zone as

> For example, the following will parse:
>
> ```
> "Europe/London"           -- ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
> "Z"                       -- ZoneOffset.UTC
> "UT"                      -- ZoneId.of("UT")
> "UTC"                     -- ZoneId.of("UTC")
> "GMT"                     -- ZoneId.of("GMT")
> "+01:30"                  -- ZoneOffset.of("+01:30")
> "UT+01:30"                -- ZoneOffset.of("+01:30")
> "UTC+01:30"               -- ZoneOffset.of("+01:30")
> "GMT+01:30"               -- ZoneOffset.of("+01:30")
> ```

You can define your own date time format to allow hour offsets, but many places in the world have fractions of an hour such as Nepal which is +05:45 and North Korea which recently changed to +08:30

Comment: "+01" is standard shorthand for "+01:00". I understand there are non-even offsets, like "+05:45" in which case you can use that and you can't omit the minutes.

Comment: Secondly, I don't want to write custom extensions or define my own "date time format". I want the datetime library to parse standard iso8601 strings that I get from external sources. The JDK8 can't seem to do that.

Comment: @clay " JDK8 can't seem to do that." When the JDK8 doesn't already do exactly what we want, as developers, that's why we write code.

Comment: when the JDK has a very blatant bug in adhering to a standard for no good reason, sure maybe you hack your own solution or use a third party library in the meantime to get an app working, but a good citizen should file a bug report. There is no reason this shouldn't be fixed in the core JDK.

Comment: @clay The development team do have a habit of leaving accepted bugs for a very long time (years)  From what I hear is; that it depends on who is asking for the fix, the loudest clients get their bugs fixed first.

Comment: I think there is large misunderstanding of role of ISO-8601. It is NOT a concise standard for one format to use -- rather, it defines a family of configurable representations. So claiming "JDK8 doesn't do ISO-8601" is incorrect, as it assumes that the _default_ format should allow all possible permutations of ISO-8601 types. I also do not necessarily understand aversion to specifying date formats: that's what developers do, just like @PeterLawrey said.

Answer (score 0):

Thx @mkczyk said I made my own formatter for the job.
I needed a parser for date's like

1. "2016-02-14T18:32:04.150Z"
2. "2016-02-14T21:32:04.150+04"
3. "2016-02-14T21:32:04.150+04:00"

`private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_NANOSECONDS_OFFSET_FORMATTER = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
            .appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
            .toFormatter();`

Struggled a bit with appendfraction(..,..,..,true) considers nanoseconds as decimal of seconds.

`ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(textToParse, DATE_TIME_NANOSECONDS_OFFSET_FORMATTER);`

And after that used to get UTC time from it.

```
zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(zdt.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```