# OffsetDateTime parse different behavior in Java 8 and Java 11

Tags: java

When I execute this in Java 8

```
String fromDate = "2007-12-03T10:15:30+01";
OffsetDateTime from = OffsetDateTime.parse(fromDate);
```

I receive the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2007-12-03T10:15:30+01' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:6)
```

But when doing the same in Java 11 it passes just fine. 
What has changed? In Javadoc I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Java 8 and Java 11 use ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME as a default DateTimeFormatter:

```
public static OffsetDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

The implementation of ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME has changed, which is documented in the javadoc

Java 11 [ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)

> The offset ID. If the offset has seconds then they will be handled even though this is not part of the ISO-8601 standard. **The offset parsing is lenient, which allows the minutes and seconds to be optional.** Parsing is case insensitive.

Java 8 [ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)

> The offset ID. If the offset has seconds then they will be handled even though this is not part of the ISO-8601 standard. Parsing is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug [JDK-8032051](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032051) fixed in JDK9.
In JDK8 is not `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` fully ISO-8601 compliant, because does not support lenient timezone format like `+01`. You can try with TZ `+01:00`, it will be parsed successfully.

Because this bug also affects `ZonedDateTime` (fix have been applied in [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/8414d01b81db)), you can look at [java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse and iso8601?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079459/java-time-zoneddatetime-parse-and-iso8601) for possible solutions.